# Integer solutions to combinations of floating point numbers round 2

Tags: real-analysis

Couldn't find how to re-open a topic so I'll re-ask.

Imagine two kids each sitting in the center of their own tilt-a whirl®, each holding steady a flashlight (or laser) whose beam is parallel to the deck. Each machine rotates and precesses (we'll leave out nutation) at different, real, rates. How do we determine the least number of rotations to alignment, for each kid.

If you prefer another analogy: Saturn and Jupiter orbit with different (real) periods. How many orbits for each until conjunction in precisely the same position in space? Simplify by assuming circular, observer-centric, orbits.

specifically solutions to:

aC1 + bC2 = N

where a, b, N are positive integers of your own choosing and C1, C2 are constant, unique, positive, non-integer(real) numbers where C1 < C2.

I am hoping to avoid rigorous computational methods involving modulus tests.

Hope I clarified the ambiguities.

Thanks, @DonThousand the Bezout identity looks interesting.

Comment: Duplicate: [Integer solutions to combinations of floating point numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169241/integer-solutions-to-combinations-of-floating-point-numbers). Please do not reask the same question. Instead, get it reopened.

Comment: Instead of telling me "to get it reopened", please provide a link to explain how to do so.

Comment: Try to make your case [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today)

Comment: The following generic advice will help you get your original problem re-opened.  I don't necessarily agree with the pertinent mathSE guidelines, but they do exist, so your best approach is to accommodate them.  You need to **impress** mathSE reviewers; unfortunately, this will not be easy.  If you **edit your original question** so that it adheres as closely as possible to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), this **will** impress mathSE reviewers.